How can I cross an overpass in "Street View" without being dropped to the roadway below?
I am trying to use Google Street View in Google Maps and Google Earth to explore an unfamiliar area to avoid getting lost a second time but I'm having trouble negotiating an overpass.
As I progress along Lawn Avenue I reach a point where it passes over Route 309.  Every time I try cross the overpass I'm dropped down onto the underpass below (RTE 309).
How can I successfully cross an overpass in "Street View"?
Google Maps Street View

Overpass Street View ( link )
Lawn Ave NW approaching Route 309 overpass  

Underpass/RTE 309 Street View ( link )
Still facing NW but now on Route 309 directly below overpass




While, this behavior may appear counterintuitive at first, upon reflection it provides a mechanism to move between road levels within Street View.

Don't advance by clicking on the lower portion of the image (road).
 
Click on the upper portion of the map (sky) to advance.
 
Should you wish/need to move from the underpass back to the overpass, use a similar technique raising the mouse pointer until the direction of advance changes and matches the overpass.
 


  Warning
All stunts were performed by professionals on a closed virtual course. Dropping unexpectedly onto roadways carries significant risk of property damage, serious injury, and even death.  Always exit overpasses using the ramps provided and keep your vehicle well-maintained and your mouse lint-free.

Normally when you move between road levels an ambulance shows up..

Given the inherent risks, I added a warning to the answer.

I suppose there are some very literal-minded folks out there :-)

Alternative answer:  use up/down arrow keys on the keyboard to step forward/back.

Thanks.  I've been falling through overpasses for so long :-)  I avoid the keyboard. For me it's a mine-field of accidental keystroke shortcuts to hell.
